# Копирование параметров

Tags: jquery, javascript, форма

Есть много картинок, у любой картинки alt='12' числа разные. Как сделать, чтобы этот альт параметр скопировался в `input hidden value`. В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1):

```
var alt = $(".image").attr('alt');

$("input[type='hidden']").val(alt);
```

Comment: поставил на онклик при клике на изображение но что то никак...

Comment: @big-vl, давайте полный код, откуда я знаю какая у вас структура. Вы спросили куда копать вот я и показал